# htmlspecialchars() function is not working in laravel

Tags: php, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

I am trying to convert special characters to html entities.
here is my string
`$string = "cook 'n eat";`
I am expecting this output `cook &#039n eat`. But the output is same as the input string.
I have used both `htmlspecialchars()` and `htmlentities()`.

```
$string = "cook 'n eat";
echo htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Please suggest me what is wrong and how to solve. Please make it solution for all kind of special characters

Comment: No https://3v4l.org/ZpUUX. Viewing in a browser will render the entity as `'` obviously.  You could wrap in `<pre>` tags.

Comment: i am returning the string from a laravel controller and it doesnt work there. Pre tag is not going to work in my context.